# SSMA error "Assembly 'SSMA4OracleSQLServerExtensions.NET' was not found in the SQL catalog"

Tags: ssma

everyone.

I am attempting to do a simple test migration of a table with 4 columns and 1 row from Oracle to SQL using SSMA.
Brand new VM with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and brand new SQL 2019 Dev ver 15.0.4083.2.
Installed SSMA for Oracle 8.18.0 and SSMA for Oracle ExtensionPack_8.18.0.

When I do sync with database after converting schemas I get this error:
Errors: CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'SSMA4OracleSQLServerCollections.NET' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using sp_add_trusted_assembly.

I made sure that 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 0 but I still get the same error.

I see 3 assemblies in the GUI of SSMA:
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
SSMA4OracleSQLServerCollections.NET
SSMA4OracleSQLServerCollections.NET
I checked and all the files are present in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle\bin".

Tried to reinstall SSMA and got the same error.
Tried it on a different server – same error.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click assembly and select synchronize with database.
This will transfer assembly definition into database.